Random FPS drop every time camera finished initialized in OpenCVSharp
My app is Winforms Desktop app using OpenCV to record and stored video files. I'm currently using
VideoCapture videoCapture = VideoCapture.FromCamera(index: cameraIndex, apiPreference: VideoCaptureAPIs.DSHOW);

And it worked fine for the most part. But then about few days ago, My client reported that sometimes after the app loaded and the camera finished initialization process, The FPS dropped to basically 1-5FPS and look very choppy unless they restart the app. I'm able to reproduced by repeatedly re-initialized VideoCapture and it just happened randomly. So i've been basically spending 2 full days trial & error my way to hunting them down. But no luck.
Although I found out that if i change my apiPreferences to VideoCaptureAPIs.MSMF the issue is basically solved. Plus the performance gain is very noticable. But it leads to another problem similar to this issue. So now i'm really ran out of options. I'm also not entirely sure that the API is the one causing the issue, and it might be sloppy code on my part. But i'm basically hitting the real dead-end here.
I'll try to reproduced with an example. But in the meantime if you can, take a look at my snippet. You may know something that i don't. Thanks!
Create VideoCapture in OpenCVHelper. I'm using DsDevice to get cameraIndex
public VideoCapture CreateVideoCaptureFromCamera(int cameraIndex, int width, int height, double inputFPS, int IsAutoFocus)
{
    try
    {
        VideoCapture videoCapture = VideoCapture.FromCamera(index: cameraIndex, apiPreference: VideoCaptureAPIs.DSHOW);
        videoCapture.FrameHeight = height;
        videoCapture.FrameWidth = width;
        videoCapture.Fps = inputFPS;

        if (IsAutoFocus == (int)AutoFocusStatus.On)
        {
            videoCapture.AutoFocus = true;
        }
        else
        {
            videoCapture.AutoFocus = false;
            videoCapture.Focus = 100;
        }
        videoCapture.Zoom = 0;
        videoCapture.FourCC = "MJPG";
        return videoCapture;
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
}

Now in Presenter layer. Create Video Capture and utilized Multithreading.
videoCapturePresenter = recorderMainAppManager.CreateVideoCapture(
    index: camera.Index,
    resolution: resolution, //resolutions[resolutions.Count - 1],
    fps: ProfilePresenter.CameraFps,
    focus: ProfilePresenter.IsAutoFocus ?? (int)AutoFocusStatus.Off
);
captureTokenSource = new();
_captureThread = new Thread(() => CaptureFrame(videoCapturePresenter, captureTokenSource))
{
    Name = "Capture Thread",
    Priority = ThreadPriority.AboveNormal, ///This is not the cause because i added after i can reproduced the issues. 
};
_captureThread.Start();

This is CaptureFrame. I used Cv2.Resize to resize the frame to PictureBox size before bringing it to the UI layer. Without it PictureBox will attempted to resize each frame by itself and take half of my available RAM along with it.
private void CaptureFrame(VideoCapture capture, CancellationTokenSource captureToken)
{
    
    string newOverlayText = string.Empty;
    try
    {
        ShipmentOverlay shipmentOverlay = recorderMainAppManager.GetShipmentOverlay
            (
                resolution: $"{capture.FrameWidth}x{capture.FrameHeight}"
            );

        string username = $"Employee Name : {UserPresenter.Username}";
        while (!captureToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            string datetime = DateTimeOffset.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
            string overlayText = createNewOverlayString();
            using (Mat rawFrame = new())
            {
                newOverlayText = $"Date : {datetime} | {username} | {overlayText}";
                if (!capture.Read(rawFrame))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error: Failed to read frame.");
                    break;
                }

                if (rawFrame.Empty())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error: Empty frame.");
                    break;
                }

                using (Mat frameWithOverlay = recorderMainAppManager.DrawOverlay(frame: rawFrame, shipmentOverlay: shipmentOverlay, overlayText: newOverlayText))
                {
                    Mat clonedFrame = frameWithOverlay.Clone();
                    {
                        lock (clonedFrame)
                        {
                            var currentPictureBox = recorderMainAppView.GetPicRecordResolution();
                            var targetSize = new OpenCvSharp.Size() { Width = currentPictureBox.Width, Height = currentPictureBox.Height };
                            if (targetSize.Width > 0 && targetSize.Height > 0)
                            {
                                Mat captureMat = new();
                                Cv2.Resize(clonedFrame, captureMat, targetSize, interpolation: InterpolationFlags.Area);
                                using (Bitmap _bitmap = BitmapConverter.ToBitmap(captureMat))
                                {
                                    Bitmap clonedResizeFrame = (Bitmap)_bitmap.Clone();
                                    recorderMainAppView.UpdateCameraView(clonedResizeFrame);
                                }

                                if (_isRecording == RecordStatus.RECORD)
                                {
                                    _frameQueue.Enqueue(clonedFrame);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    captureMat.Dispose();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            _threadStopEvent.Wait(1);
            if (captureToken.IsCancellationRequested) break;
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
}

This is UI layer. When my camera start producing a frame, it will be sent to PictureBox as video preview for my user.
public void UpdateCameraView(Bitmap img)
{
    try
    {
        if (picRecord.InvokeRequired && 
            WindowState != FormWindowState.Minimized)
        {
            using (picRecord.Image)
            {
                Invoke(() => picRecord.Image = img);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (ObjectDisposedException)
    {
        // This function throw everytime in debug mode, apparently because some video frame aren't being disposed yet
        // But frmMain is already disposed. Happened only when i exit the app.
        // For now, do nothing. But if you know how to solve this. Feel free.
        return;
    }
}

Edit : This is where _frameQueue goes, As requested. I didn't think it's really related to the question since it's on separated thread and doesn't start until user's input. But the issue occured even before this process even begin.
First, another thread is being spawned. This is for turning each frame into video files upon User's recording input.
videoWriterPresenter = recorderMainAppManager.CreateVideoWriter(
    capture: videoCapturePresenter,
    savedDir: outputDirectory,
    BaseLabel: data.FirstOrDefault(t => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(t)));
_threadStopEvent.Reset();
writerTokenSource = new();
_writerThread = new Thread(() => WriteFrame(writerTokenSource))
{
    Name = "Writer Thread",
    IsBackground = true
};
_writerThread.Start();

private void WriteFrame(CancellationTokenSource writerToken)
{
    Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    double _delay = 1_000 / videoCapturePresenter!.Fps;
    try
    {
        while (!_threadStopEvent.Wait(0) && !writerToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            if (stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds <= _delay)
            {
                _threadStopEvent.Wait(1);
                continue;
            }

            while (_frameQueue.Count != 0)
            {
                if (_frameQueue.TryDequeue(out Mat? frameDequeue))
                {
                    using (frameDequeue)
                    {
                        videoWriterPresenter!.Write(frameDequeue);
                    }
                    _threadStopEvent.Wait(1);
                    stopwatch.Restart();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        stopwatch.Stop();
    }
}


What I can tell you here is that you have two heavy disposable objects that are not disposed, 2 objects are cloned for no reason: one is a Mat that is added to _frameQueue, and it's not clear what is happening with it (are you processing it somewhere else? Does it live in memory? For how long?), the other is the Bitmap that you're assigning to a PictureBox. This object is never disposed. So, you have, potentially, at least 3 or 4 large objects that are parked in memory at the same time, and at least 2 of them are never disposed. This spells doom for your app

Specify what the lock and _frameQueue are there for

@Jimi _frameQueue is being sent to another function WriteFrame which is responsible for writing each frame into video files. I'm gonna edit and put the function here.
